# php array indexes type mismatch in visual studio code

Tags: php, arrays, visual-studio-code

I've tried to find a post regarding my problem but found nothing. Maybe I'm not using the correct keywords. Anyway, this is my problem.

Let's say I create an array called $bike and with the following indexes:

```
$bike = array("name" => "Ducati", "available" => true, "stock" => 3)
```

So `"name"` is of type `string`, `"available"` of type `bool` and `"stock"` of type `int`

if in my code I use

```
echo ucfirst($bike["name"]);
```

alone, no problems occur. But, if my code is

```
echo $bike["stock"];
echo ucfirst($bike["name"]);
```

the second line is underlined in red with the error: `Expected type 'string'. Found 'int[]'`

or again, if my code is

```
echo $bike["available"];
echo ucfirst($bike["name"]);
```

the second line is underlined in red with the error: `Expected type 'string'. Found 'bool'`

without the `ucfirst()` function no error occurs

```
echo $bike["available"];
echo $bike["name"];
```

if preceded by a let's say int index but of another array, no error occurs

```
echo $car["stock"];
echo ucfirst($bike["name"]);
```

So, `$bike["name"]`, when alone is correctly seen as a string, if preceded by an index of different type of the same array is seen as that index type, and the `ucfirst()` function obviously doesn't like it.

I think I get that is a PHP problem of declaring the type of every single index and I found some posts about it, even on stack overflow, but all answers are very complicated and confusing and I'm not getting how to solve it.

Can anyone give me an "easy to understand" answer and solution?

Thanks

Comment: Your variables must have `$`. Also you can create an [mcve] and add to question.

Comment: sorry, typo in my question. All my variables have $

Comment: Also string keys of array must be in `'`: `'name'`, `'stock'` etc

Comment: And now - this code works https://3v4l.org/RJ9Zp.

Comment: @u_mulder The issue doesn't seem to be if the code works or not, just how to get rid of the bogus warning in VScode

Comment: the code that gives me the error is much more complex than the one I've posted. I'll try to make a postable example giving the error.

Comment: I also thought there was no difference in using Single vs. Double quotes...

Comment: Which extension reported the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type hinting for mixed arrays is tricky.

When Visual Studio sees this, it assumes that $bike is an array of string, since the value at that index is a string:

`echo ucfirst($bike["name"]);`

Similarly, when you write this, it will assume $bike is an array of int:

`echo $bike["stock"];`

So if the next key you access does not hold the same type, it's throws an error.

If bikes have the same information, then you might be better off with a Data Transfer Object (or DTO) - which is a very light class with no methods (okay, sometimes a method each to go from/to an array):

```
class Bike
{
  public function __construct(
    public string $name,
    public int $stock = 0,
    public bool $available = false,
  ) {
    //
  }
}
```

Of course, this level of type safety isn't necessary for PHP itself - which will happily work with arrays of mixed types, and a bunch of other loosely goosey typing.
But as you get into more complex application design, type safety and static analysis can help prevent problems that might come up with putting the wrong type in the wrong place without having to write explicit tests. It also helps inform other developers what is expected by more complex data types like Bike or User, or whatever.

It also means that you can typehint the Bike dataobject where you want to use it in a method - and be warned if your code might be trying to pass something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer HorusKol. To be honest I was waiting for it. I kinda had the feeling classes where the answer but I was wandering if it was just a Visual studio code problem, or, if a php mixed arrays problem, if there was a simpler fix than DTO